# Excel VBA - Groupings - Summary Rows Below Detail

Tags: excel, vba

I am using arrays to group my data on the spreadsheet. By default the setting Summary Rows Below Detail is enabled.  If I run my macro the + or expanding sign ends up at the bottom of the group.  If I disable the setting, the + or expanding sign is at the top of the group as I want it.

To save the end user the hassle of manually unchecking this option I included the code to disable the setting, although the + sign is at the top, my groupings are wrong.  I'll work through the loops in my array to see where it is going wrong, but I do not understand how it could be if it works when I manually disable the setting.

This is my code to disable the setting

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Selection.AutoOutline
With ActiveSheet.Outline
    .SummaryRow = xlAbove
End With
```

Is this correct?

Cheers